# How select somefunction('1 * 2 / 2 + 3') = 4 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can use below code get int result in C#

```
new DataTable().Compute("1 * 2 / 2 + 3", string.Empty);//result:4
```

How can I do it in SQL Server? I expect `convert and operation string to int`.
My solution is CLR , but there is no any original solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the `somfunction` already written out in CLR, and want to be able to call it from SQL Server?

Comment: yes @tarheel It is a last resort

Comment: You'll have to create the assembly (dll) of the CLR, and a corresponding UDF in SQL Server to call the assembly. I would start with this [CLR page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017) of of the SQL Server docs.

Comment: [tarheel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960362/tarheel) thanks,it looks like i have no other choice. you can answer this question below,i'll accept your answer.

Comment: *Why* would you want to use SQL to parse and evaluate strings into arbitrary mathematic expressions? Why do you want to build a calculator out of SQL? The database is for storage and retrieval of data. Besides, all DataTable.Compute() is doing is creating the equivalent of a [SQL Server computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) in the DataTable. Your example works, but that's not remotely the intent of the method.

Comment: [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) In my case ,my boss want to know all compute logic and get result.Ex.result is 4,but he also want know my program compute logic `1 * 2 / 2 + 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you need to do.

1. Create the assembly with the CLR logic you already have.
2. On the SQL Server side, create a User-Defined Function that calls the assembly.

This is an example of what the UDF would look like from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-scalar-valued-functions?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY FirstUdf FROM 'FirstUdf.dll';  
GO  

CREATE FUNCTION CountSalesOrderHeader() RETURNS INT   
AS EXTERNAL NAME FirstUdf.T.ReturnOrderCount;   
GO  

SELECT dbo.CountSalesOrderHeader();  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write like it is

```
select 1 * 2 / 2 + 3
```

[image]

Comment: I expect `select somefunction('1 * 2 / 2 + 3') to 4` not `select 1 * 2 / 2 + 3`,it's different.

Comment: create the function and then pass the parameter